# How do I make my ScrollView dynamically change when adding lines to my EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

https://gyazo.com/1940054eacbe2e3388ac9e6da0eb2cb1

I have a linear layout, nested in a relative layout, nested in a scrollview. When I add lines to my EditText the scroll bar doesn't dynamically update, it still acts as if it's at the top of the page.

I have set the fillViewport of my ScrollViews to true, I have changed every imaginable component's height constraints to every possible variation of constraint.

Any ideas would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of soft-keyboard.Add this to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

OR

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

for example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```