# EditText's built-in scroll does not scroll till the end when keyboard is showing - the keyboard hides the text at the bottom

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I made a video to show that when scrolling till the end the keyboard hides the text at the bottom:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/XZRDphEmAh5aR9D78

if you want to check out the app and the GitHub project and play around with the app and code for yourself you will find that here: [supernote.org](https://supernote.org)

I already tried various stuff in the manifest like:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

So this is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:activity=".EditNoteActivity"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEditNoteActivity"
    >
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_title"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:gravity="top"
            />



        <EditText
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor"
            android:background="@null"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

OR

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

for example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901233/how-do-i-make-my-scrollview-dynamically-change-when-adding-lines-to-my-edittext/58901286#58901286) and my answer to that question, He had a similar issue.

**Update:**

Try ConstraintLayout Instead of LinearLayout..

Comment: I specifically mentioned already trying that... did I try it wrong?

Comment: Maybe it was not there at the time of me posting this answer or maybe i missed it, share your manifest and check my answer update

Comment: It worked now, for some mysterious reason.It's cutting out my other edit text, even when it is focused on it but I guess that's a new issue...

Comment: As i mentioned, you can have greater controll with constraint layouts and you should also handle soft keyboard to manually make changes to edittext like scrolling it on size change or setting visibility of other edittexts to gone can give you a greater work area